# Use Kindle Touch as secondary display for my linux PC

Tags: kindle

I have an old Kinle Touch (D01200) layning around, and I was wondering if I could use it as a second display?

I can jailreak it with this: https://the-digital-reader.com/2011/12/10/kindle-touch-gets-worlds-simplest-jailbreak-and-it-runs-html5/

And someone did something similar with this: https://lifehacker.com/turn-your-kindle-into-a-second-monitor-5928912

I don't know if this is at all relevent to this project, but it works for kinlde fires: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/use-your-kindle-as-a-second-display

I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

Comment: You're wondering if you could, but I've gotta ask if you SHOULD. E-ink displays have very high latency and, while designed for semi static text, are NOT designed for, or even capable of any sort of dynamic content.

Comment: I'm not sure what Jailbreaking adds to this device, but you'd need either an app that runs on the device that offers some sort of display target endpoint, likely using a service of some sort either running on the source computer or some third party server. You should start by looking at the possible ways to get display content on the Kindle, and then look at which of those methods can run from your computer.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I've done, however it is a kindle, so you can't just "get apps" on it.

Comment: @music2myear I'm planning on usiing it for reading. It's much better for your eyes.

Comment: Then you should use one of the existing systems for getting content to the device. I have a Paperwhite and Amazon gave me an email address I can send things to which it then converts and sends to the device. It isn't instantaneous, but it does all the conversion and formatting for you.

Comment: I mean for reading a website, like reddit, or the likes. Not reading a book. It's fine, I should have asked on there anyways.